# Cannot print words from file using Java and Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to scan through a text file and only print out strings containing letters using regex.

my current code keeps returning false when I use regex.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DocumentReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File inputFile = new File("document.txt"); // document
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);            

        while (in.hasNext()){

            String input = in.next();
            input.matches("([^a-zA-Z])");
            System.out.println(input.matches("[^a-zA-Z]"));
            System.out.println(input);


            //if text matches regex, print text
            if (input.matches("[^a-zA-Z]")){
            System.out.println(input);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you mean `[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue : `[^a-zA-Z]` mean match single non-alphabet character .

Since you want to match `containing letters`use

- `[a-zA-Z]+` one or more alphabets as given in the `[]`

Code :

```
    File inputFile = new File("document.txt"); // document
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);            

    while (in.hasNext()){

        String input = in.next();
        //input.matches("([^a-zA-Z])"); not required
        System.out.println(input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")+"\n"+input);

        //if text matches regex, print text
        if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
            System.out.println(input);
        }
```

Demo

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('abcd'));
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test('%s')); // ignore ^ $ , matches add it by default
```